# JSON field values mapping with solr field using Nifi

Tags: json, solr, apache-nifi

I have a JSON file as below and I need to map the values of the JSON to respective fields in Solr collection. Below is my JSON data.

```json
[
  {
    "objectId": "9864d5c0-1409-4863-bbb9-e6d1437eaf7d",
    "platform": "nifi",
    "bulletinId": 1561039,
    "bulletinCategory": "Log Message",
    "bulletinGroupId": "95c71c6a-0185-1000-0547-fbc467f25c4c"
  }
]
```

My solr fields are object_id, platform, id, category, group_id. I want to map the values of JSON to these fields.

or is there a possible way to replace the field names of JSON as required and then ingest into Solr using Replace text?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can easily use a **shift** transformation within a **JoltTransformJSON** process  containing the following specification
`[
  {
    "objectId": "object_id",
    "platform": "&",
    "bulletinId": "id",
    "bulletinCategory": "category",
    "bulletinGroupId": "group_id"
   }
]`

Comment: Hi @ Barbaros Özhan we can use Jolt transform but it caused performance issue last time when I used it, so I'm searching for an alternative suggested by my Superior.

Comment: OK @Ram good luck. Btw, fixed spec is `[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "objectId": "object_id",
        "platform": "&",
        "bulletinId": "id",
        "bulletinCategory": "category",
        "bulletinGroupId": "group_id"
      }
    }
  }
]`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan  I have tried using your approach, but my values are coming multiple times in a single flowfile whic is causing error while ingesting it to solr collection  like this                                                                                                                       
 "category" : [ "Log Message", "Log Message", "Log Message", "Log Message", "Log Message" ],      I have used       Jolt Transformation DSL as Chain   in processor.

Comment: well, but I don't know how style did you try. Can you please edit the question with this information?